# Are app settings in Azure case-sensitive or not or somethng in-between?

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-cli

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=cli#configure-app-settings) I can set the values using [this syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-appsettings-set). As far I can see, nothing is mentioned regarding the case sensitivity.

When I execute this:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --settings test01="lower-cased" ...
```

it behaves as expected. Then, executing the following:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --settings test01="lower-cased to be upped" ...
```

also performs as expected (updating the value). However, execution of the below produces an error.

```
az webapp config appsettings set --settings Test01="upper-cased" ...
```

That surprises me because if Azure is case-sensitive, then no collision should occur, hence allowing me to have two independent variables (i.e. *test01* and *Test01*). Conversely, if it is case-insensitive, then no collision should occur neither, hence updating the previously set value.

Instead, I see this error message. It confuses me.

> Operation returned an invalid status 'Conflict'

Comment: Azure App Service app-settings are (last time I checked) exposed to the application as environment-variables, which do not have case-sensitive names on Windows. If your App Service is running in a Linux-based AppServicePlan then the behaviour will be different. HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior as it is due the case sensitivity of Azure App Service settings.

If you provide same name of setting with same case-sensitivity, then it will update the setting with new value:

[image]

[image]

If you try changing case and and execute command, you will get **conflict error**  because App setting thinks Test and test both are same and it thinks it as a duplicate as @Dai said.

[image]

Comment: I still don't get it. If it thinks those are the same, hence duplicates (as you say), then why not update the value? After all, those are then considered to be duplicates. Or are they not? It seems so fishy...

Comment: For updating the value, it needs to be the same which you have given while creating it, but in the backend it stores as same or as duplicate, its a rule( or Inbuilt thing) of azure cli and Azure services and their services. If you still feel something fishy, I would suggest you to raise a support request for this.

Comment: I doubt my *it feels fishy* will have a significant impact on their consideration. I understand that it simply is how it works. It's just confusing that a value is considered a duplicate when fetching it but as a distinct when storing it. So Azure is, in that sense, **both** case-sensitive and case-insensitive.